# How to correctly parse JSON with Unicode escape sequences?

Tags: rust, unicode, escaping, serde-json

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b5bee9772f0b6f8ebea7b13c9b51b20a)

```rust
use serde_json::json; // 1.0.66
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let input = "{\"a\": \"b\\u001fc\"}";
    let bytes = input.as_bytes();
    let json: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_slice(bytes).unwrap();
    for (_k, v) in json.as_object().unwrap() {
        let vec = serde_json::to_vec(v).unwrap();
        let utf8_str = str::from_utf8(&vec).unwrap();
        println!("value: {}", v);
        println!("utf8_str: {}", utf8_str);
        println!("bytes: {:?}", vec);
    }
}
```

How can the value of object key `"a"` be transformed into the following string?

```
b\u{1f}c
```

I've tried with `serde_json` and `str::from_utf8`, but I always get `"b\u001fc"` as the result. The escaped character sequence is not interpreted correctly. How this can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```rust
let vec = serde_json::to_vec(v).unwrap();
```

From the `serde_json` docs on [`to_vec()`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.to_vec.html):

> Serialize the given data structure as a JSON byte vector.

You are deserializing from JSON, getting the values of the object, serializing them back to JSON and printing that. You don't want to serialize back to JSON, you want to print the "raw" string, so something like this does what you want:

```rust
fn main() {
    let input = "{\"a\": \"b\\u001fc\"}";
    let bytes = input.as_bytes();
    let json: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_slice(bytes).unwrap();
    for (_k, v) in json.as_object().unwrap() {
        let string = v.as_str().unwrap();
        println!("bytes: {:?}", string);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=611b4cfaa507a2441382de314691dbc1)

Answer (score 2):

I think things are closer to working than you think. Your problem is not that the escape sequence isn't being interpreted correctly, but rather that `serde_json::to_vec(v)` essentially re-encodes `v` (which is `serde_json::value::Value::String`) into a vector of *JSON-encoded* bytes. This means that it picks up the surrounding quote characters (byte `34`) and turns the escape sequence into a literal `['\\', 'u', ...]` — because that's how it would look in JSON.

If you want to get the string value out, you can do this:

```
for (_k, v) in json.as_object().unwrap() {
    if let serde_json::value::Value::String(s) = v {
        println!("{:?}", s);
    }
}
```

This prints `"b\u{1f}c"`, the Rust string you want.